# Algorithm for betting and particularly winning the bet?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, python-3.x

I have a game where two teams (red and blue) fight against each other.
Spectators can place a bet on one of the two teams, adding a new bet to the `bets` dict, which eventually looks like this (after bets have been made):

```
# Example of what 'bets' dict might look like mid-game
bets = {
    # player_id: (team, amount),
    12: (TEAM_RED, 500),
    13: (TEAM_RED, 1200),
    3: (TEAM_BLUE, 300),
    7: (TEAM_BLUE, 1500)
}
```

Once the game is over, I wish to divide the total pot for  each player based on how much they betted.
So on the scenario above, if blue team were to win, player with id of **3** would get only a fifth of what player with id **7** gets, and players **12** and **13** get nothing.

I'm not sure how to calculate how much money should each player get, how'd I do that?
I think I should get the factor between the two teams somehow, and multiply the players' bet by that amount?

Comment: Add up the total number of bets per team, and divide each player's bet by the total to get the percentage of winnings they earn. So, in this case, the total bets on `TEAM_BLUE` is `1800`, so Player `3`'s cut is` (300 / 1800) * (total money)`

Comment: @RPGillespie That's actually damn simple. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [pari-mutuel payout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parimutuel_betting). You simply divide the total money bet among the winners in proportion to their bets (and if you're a racetrack, after taking 10% vig off the top :-(

So first get the total amount bet:

```
total = sum(x[1] for x in bets.values());
```

then the total of correct bets:

```
wtotal = sum(x[1] for x in bets.values() if x[0] == TEAM_BLUE);
```

then go though the bettors:

```
for p in bets.keys():
    if bets[p][0] == TEAM_BLUE:
        payout = total * bets[p][1] / wtotal
```

Comment: After reading your answer, I realise mine is horribly naive. +1.

Comment: You were also only paying out half the money. Remind me not to go to your racetrack. :-)

Comment: Ahh thanks for the explanation, made your answer simpler for me to understand :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: if someone bets 1 on blue and someone else bets 1000 on red, then blue would earn 1001 on this algorithm - which doesn't seem right

Comment: @K2xL Perfectly even bet if the odds of Red winning were 1 out of 1001. Someone would have to bet 1 on Blue 1001 times to break even according to the odds. If the "actual" odds were more even, say 50/50, then somebody over bet on Red.